# What does "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'" mean? And how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, python-3.4, slice

```
accounts = {"key":"value","thy":"l23","user2":"psw2"}
a = input("Enter username: ")
b = input("Enter password: ")
if accounts[a:b] == True:
    print("Welcome")
```

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

What does the error mean? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do (validate a username and password), you need to go about it this way:

```
accounts = {"key":"value","thy":"l23","user2":"psw2"}
a = input("Enter username: ")
b = input("Enter password: ")
if accounts[a] and accounts[a] == b:
    print("Welcome")
```

This tests to see if a password exists for the entered user, then tests to see if the entered password matches the one stored in `accounts`.

The major problem with this method is that the entered password is printed out when you type it in. To get around this, use the [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) function.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help! Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

The

```
if accounts[a:b] == True:
```

should read

```
if accounts.get(a) == b:
```

The reason I used `accounts.get(a)` instead of `accounts[a]` is that the former would return `None` if `a` does not contain a valid username (the latter would raise an exception).

Comment: Thank you for your help!